# Possible to loop through a list of variables, with names differ by numbers only?

Tags: c#, winforms

For example in Windows Form, you have textboxes textbox0 to textbox29 and you need to assign them all to an array. What I currently can think of is to do this:

```
array[0] = textbox0;
array[1] = textbox1;
...
array[29] = textbox29;
```

Is it possible for me to do something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
{
    array[i] = textbox + i; 
    //and some magic is done such tt this is a variable, eg. textbox1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am modifying @rdkleine code

```
Control[] array = new Control[100];
foreach (Control c in FormX.Controls)
{
    int index;
    if (c.Name.StartsWith("textbox") && int.TryParse(c.Name.Substring(7),out index))
    {
        array[index] = c;
    }
}
```

I think this should place the controls in the correct index in the array.

Comment: Unless there are more then 100 controls. Use Array.Resize().

Comment: Or Control[] array = new Control[Formx.Controls.Count]. This way we will accomodate all the controls.

Comment: just realised tt default by Windows Form is start from 1 n also need to cast, so i hv to use array[index-1] = (TextBox)c;

Answer (score 5):

```
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray()
```

should work. It selects the controls which are TextBox and then converts them to an array.

Comment: This could result in the name not correlating with the array index if the controls are out-of-order on the page. For example, `array[0]` might contain `textbox7` etc. Not sure whether or not this would be a problem for the OP.

Comment: Depending on the naming convention you could chain some more LINQ methods together to refine the selection:              this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(c => c.Text.StartsWith("textbox")).OrderBy(c => c.Text).ToArray();

Answer (score 4):

From the top of my head:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (Control c in FormX.Controls)
{
    int i2;
    if (c.Name.StartsWith("textbox") && int.TryParse(c.Name.Substring(7),out i2))
    {
        array[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
}
array = array.OrderBy(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.Name.Substring(7))).ToArray();
```

Comment: This could result in the name not correlating with the array index if the controls are out-of-order on the page. For example, `array[0]` might contain `textbox7` etc. Not sure whether or not this would be a problem for the OP.

Comment: Good one. Added sorting using System.Linq

Comment: Sorting will be aplha sorting, meaning You will get textbox1, textbox10, textbox11, textbox12, ..., textbox2, textbox20, ... etc.

Comment: There you go added sorting on number after textbox

Comment: More nitpicks: *(1)* This will fail if there happen to be other textboxes on the page with non-numeric suffixes; for example, `textboxFoo`. *(2)* If the numeric suffixes aren't continuous then there could still be a mismatch between the name and the array index; for example, if there's no `textbox8` then `array[8]` will contain `textbox9` etc.

Comment: Aaarghhh!!! ;) well ok added nitpick nr1. For nr2 I would go for another solution but would need to know where @Yeeen needs this for.

Comment: Why don't you initialize the array with a large number say array[100] and instead of saying array[i] = c; say array[i2] = c. This way a control textbox10 will be assigned to array[10].

Comment: Yes sure this could be done, I'm not sure if thats the request from Yeeen. To be honest I have no idea what he tries to accomplish using arrays with controls.

Comment: Thanks for your solution and all the discussion here. Would like to mark urs as the ans but the modified ans from sh_kamalh simplifies ur solution and is also what I thought off after looking at ur solution. Furthermore I am supposed to use VS2005 for this project, so cannot support .NET Framework 4. I shall mark ur ans as useful instead.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *could* use reflection... but personally I'd try to avoid creating all those separate variables to start with. For example, if you *really* need designer support, you could avoid creating separate variables but create the array by finding the controls by name.

Alternatively, if you can just autogenerate the controls programmatically in a loop, I'd do that.